# ubuntu 15.10 64bit build Android source 5.0 version

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-source

How can I fix this problem？When I was building the Android source of 5.0 with 
'make -j4', it was causing a problem.
This is the error log:

```
Install: out/host/linux-x86/bin/acp
Yacc: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison -d  -o out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
Lex: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.l
logtags: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/src/core/java/android/content/EventLogTags.java <= frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/EventLogTags.logtags
prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison: m4 子进程失败
build/core/binary.mk:539: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp] Error 1
make: *** 正在等待未完成的任务....
frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.l:55: warning, 无法匹配规则
flex-2.5.39: fatal internal error, exec of /usr/bin/m4 failed
build/core/binary.mk:576: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file 'out/host/linux-x86/obj32/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp'
logtags: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/src/core/java/android/speech/tts/EventLogTags.java <= frameworks/base/core/java/android/speech/tts/EventLogTags.logtags
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check carefully you have all the required packages installed https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: hi thx, it's my fault. i'm not install some dependencis. i soulution it with this command:                                                                                            `$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 \
  lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache \
  libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I get similar error when build Marshmallow `6.0.1_r1` in Ubuntu 18.04.

If you get similar errors like this:

```
build/core/binary.mk:646: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_l.cpp] Aborted (core dumped)
```

Look at the line carefully, it's a `core dumped`, so I use `coredumpctl list`, navigate to the end of list with <kbd>G</kbd>, then figure out the core dump executed path (right column) is `prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex/flex-2.5.39`

And the `PREBUILT` file shows:

```
xb@dnxb:~/my_android_src/prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex$ cat PREBUILT 
The objects in this prebuilt directory can be rebuilt
using the source archive hosted at

http://sourceforge.net/projects/flex/files/

Commands:

./configure
make CFLAGS="-static" LDFLAGS="-static"
# (Disregard the errors at the end of the build)
rm flex
make CFLAGS="-static" LDFLAGS="-static" flex
# Copy the linker command line, replace it with static libm.a
gcc  -static  -static -o flex ccl.o dfa.o ecs.o scanflags.o gen.o main.o misc.o nfa.o parse.o scan.o skel.o sym.o tblcmp.o yylex.o options.o scanopt.o buf.o tables.o tables_shared.o filter.o regex.o  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
xb@dnxb:~/my_android_src/prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex$
```

That's it, the first 2 lines said that you probably need to rebuild yourself if something went wrong since this `flex-2.5.39` binary is prebuilt in another platform.

So simply untar the `flex-2.5.39.tar.gz` of this directory, go to the extracted `flex-2.5.39` directory, then follows the `PREBUILT` instruction above.

**In short, you need to do the following steps:**

```
    cd <ANDROID_TREE_DIR>/prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/flex
    tar -zxvf flex-2.5.39.tar.gz
    cd flex-2.5.39
    make CFLAGS="-static" LDFLAGS="-static"
    rm flex
    make CFLAGS="-static" LDFLAGS="-static" flex
    /bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -static  -static -o flex ccl.o dfa.o ecs.o scanflags.o gen.o main.o misc.o nfa.o parse.o scan.o skel.o sym.o tblcmp.o yylex.o options.o scanopt.o buf.o tables.o tables_shared.o filter.o regex.o lib/libcompat.la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
    cd ..
    cp flex-2.5.39/flex .
    mv flex flex-2.5.39
    ls -la 
        flex-2.5.39 #### <<- YOUR new generated file
        flex-2.5.39.tar.gz
        MODULE_LICENSE_BSD_LIKE
        NOTICE
        PREBUILT
```

Now try to do `make <module> -j4` again, no longer abort on such error.

p/s: Alternative way will be `LANG=C make pm -j4` if you see something like `LC_*` error message.

p/s2: I also need symlink `ld` as below to fixed `'out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libart.so' failed` and `error: unsupported reloc 42`:

```
xb@dnxb:~/my_android_src$ cp prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8//x86_64-linux/bin/ld ../ld_bk #backup android source's ld first
xb@dnxb:~/my_android_src$ rm prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8//x86_64-linux/bin/ld #remove android source's ld
xb@dnxb:~/my_android_src$ ln -s /usr/bin/ld.gold prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8//x86_64-linux/bin/ld #create symlink for android source's ld to system's ld.gold
```